# Django - Rendering Model Choices in template when not using Forms or ModelForms

Tags: django, django-templates, forms

I created a model and one of the fields has choices. I created a select form in my template and the choices are not been displayed. I'm not using Forms or ModelForms for a few reasons. But my understanding is that I should be able to make this work using CHOICES in the model, building a form in the template and save the information using the object manager. How can I get the choices to populate the form?

Models.py

```
class NewRating(models.Model):

EXCELLENT = 'EX'
GOOD = 'GD'
FAIR = 'FR'
BAD = 'BD'
RATING_CHOICES = (
    (EXCELLENT, 'Excellent'),
    (GOOD, 'Good'),
    (FAIR, 'Fair'),
    (BAD, 'Bad')
)
function = models.ForeignKey(Function, related_name='frating')
timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, related_name='trating')
rating = models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

Views.py

```
def f_page(request, Function_id):
assignments = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
time = Timeline.objects.all()
ratings = NewRating.objects.all()

context = {
    'assignments': assignments,
    'time' : time,
    'ratings' : ratings,
}
return render (request, 'project/pager.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<div id=for_rat>
  {% for rated in time %}
  <form action= "/project/rated" method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{rated.segment}}
  <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{rated.year}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="month" value= "{{assignments.id}}">
      <select name="ratings">
        <option value="">Choose From List</option>
        {% for rating in ratings %}
        <option value="{{rating.choices}}">{{rating.choices}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Using  {% for rating in ratings %}
        {{rating.choices}}
        {% endfor %} is not working. Can I set the choices in the models if I'm building my own forms? If yes, what am I doing wrong that this is not rendering?

Comment: `choices` is not a property of your `NewRating` model. you should display `{{ rating.rating }}` in your template

Comment: It didn't work. No choices in the scroll down.

Comment: You're making things much harder than they need to be. There are few good reasons not to use a Form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
{% for rating in ratings %}
<select name="ratings">
    <option value="">Choose From List</option>
    {% for x, y in rating._meta.get_field('rating').choices %}
        <option value="{{ x }}">{% if rating.rating == x %} selected{% endif %}> 
            {{ y }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure that this code is outside the

```
{% for rated in time %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

block

Answer (score 1):

Easiest, simplest and the 100% working method is:

Get the objects `[lets say 'my_Model_with_choices']` with `my_Model_with_choices = yourModel.objects.first()` and you can get the choices with `my_Model_with_choices._meta.get_field('your_foreign_key_variable_name').choices`

```
def f_page(request, Function_id):
     assignments = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
     ratings = NewRating.RATING_CHOICES

context = {
    'ratings' : ratings,
}
return render (request, 'project/pager.html', context)
```

Inside HTML template:

```
<select class="custom-select col-md-5" name="ratings" id="ratings" required>
    <option disabled selected value="">Ethnic Group</option>
    {% for value, ratings_group in ratings  %}
    <option value='{{value}}'>{{ratings_group}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly not willing to use `Form` or `ModelForm`, you need to have choices to be iterable which is possible via `enum`.
You can check my sample code about how to implement choices with enums [here](https://gist.github.com/shivan1b/7b4b47344a0d11880f84e87fa2908499).

You'll have to make some tweaks to your context and template after doing this.
You might want to look [how to get the list of choices with enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).